# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: f

Tags: java, javafx-8

I need to write a program to show a picture in javafx scene, and I used ImageView to show it. But I encountered a problem.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: f
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: f

This is my code:

```
public void initialize(){
    label1.setText("success");
    imageView1.setImage(new Image("F:/a.jpg"));
}
```

Comment: use `file://` url scheme for files

Comment: @JigarJoshi That should be an answer, not a comment. Please resist the temptation to provide correct, complete answers in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try anyone code of block. I hope it would resolve your error.

```
final imageView1 imv = new imageView1();
        final Image image2 = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("a.jpg"));
        imv.setImage(image2);
```

or

```
    @FXML
    private ImageView1 imageView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        File file = new File("F:/a.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imageView.setImage(image);
    }
```

Or

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("F:/a.jpg");
Image image = new Image(input);
ImageView1 imageView = new ImageView1(image);
```

Comment: I use the second way and solve this error, and thank you!

Comment: First one wouldn't work unless the image file was moved into the same package as `Main`.

Answer (score 1):

A filename is not a URL. A URL is a URL. This URL should read `"file:/F:/a.jpg"`.